# PHP Laravel : Conditional update query from array

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5

I want to add multiple where clause and multiple field to update in a single query. The code below dosen't return error but dosen't do anything :( pls help

```
        $query = DB::table($table);
        foreach($where as $key => $value ){
            if($key != 0){
                $query -> where( $key , '=' , $value);
            }
        }
        foreach($field as $key => $value ){
            if($key != 0){
                $query -> update([$key => $value]);
            }
        }

        $result2 = $query->get();
```

Comment: You can replace the second foreach loop with `unset($field[0]); $query->update($field);`

Comment: i don't understand how can i use unset($field[0]) to solve the problem, in this case field will be empty or not? can i try to load $field and call update on array ? thks

Answer (score 0):

you can not use where inside the loop. There will be only one where clause. you can use "orWhere" along with where clause. For more details please refer this

http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/queries#selects

Comment: orWhere isn't what i want, i don't need to update where (condition1) OR (condition2) ...  but where (condition1) AND (condition2) .. so i need something similar an andWhere (if exist , i think not) ..

Answer (score 0):

This isn't working because you are not storing the new query builder constraint the a variable and when using `get()` just use your original value of `DB::table($table)`.

Do this instead:

```
    $query = DB::table($table);
    foreach($where as $key => $value ){
        if($key != 0){
            $query = $query -> where( $key , '=' , $value);
        }
    }
    foreach($field as $key => $value ){
        if($key != 0){
            $query = $query -> update([$key => $value]);
        }
    }

    $result2 = $query->get();
```

Comment: i tried this code but the result is the same, no row are updated :( i don't know why .  for example if i delete  " if($key != 0){ "  condition i have an error and the query printed is something like this:
UPDATE table_name SET field = value WHERE 0 = '' AND field = value AND ...

Comment: this is the error, but is becouse of 0 isn't a column . if i keep 0 out of query with if statement query dosen't go in error but dosen't work .maybe different approach needed 
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column '0' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from `booking` where `0` = and `iddeal` = 1 and `idplan` = 1 and `idtime` = 1)

Comment: What are you really trying to do? After evaluating your code further it seems like you try to update multiple records.

Comment: yes, i should to update multiple field with multiple condition, so multiple WHERE condition and multiple UPDATE field!

Answer (score 0):

Partial solution: with this code i can update multiple field but need multiple query, even if it is automatically. where clauses must be declared at all :( ANOTHER PROBLEM is that if i don't comment the if line it create an error but if i leave it there, one update is to attribute 0 :(

```
foreach($field as $key => $value ){
            //if($key != 0){
                DB::table($table)
                    ->where('iduser', '=', $id)
                    ->where('iddeal', '=', $id_deal)
                    ->where('idplan', '=', $id_plan)
                    ->where('idtime', '=', $id_time)
                    ->update(array($key => $value));
            //}
        }
```